# OpenCart 2 - Show Category Title on Product Page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I searched and found results, modules and solution but all are for open cart 1, i want for open cart 2.

in product.tpl

```
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <?php if ($manufacturer) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $text_manufacturer; ?> <a href="<?php echo $manufacturers; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <li><?php echo $text_model; ?> <?php echo $model; ?></li>
    <?php if ($reward) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $text_reward; ?> <?php echo $reward; ?></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <li><?php echo $text_stock; ?> <?php echo $stock; ?></li>
  </ul>
```

i want to show category title in this list. i could not find this option in admin panel then i decided to do it manually. i know must do something in product.php but no idea how to get product name

```
$data['category_title'] = $this->request->get['category_title'];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you've category id in product page url?

Comment: @SankarV no, `/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=55` just product `id`

Comment: Then you have to write a model function to fetch all the product categories.

Answer (score 0):

Pedram, Your website URL should be

```
index.php?route=product/product&path=20_27&product_id=41
```

Here the 
path=20 → category_id

But your URL have not **path** variable because you was directly go throgh on search page or home page product listing. If you want to get category title then you want to develop code through product_id.

Here is code to Getting Category Title

> product.php → controller file

```
$Categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryName($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

> category.php → Model file

```
public function getCategoryName($product_id) {
       $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(cd.name),p2c.product_id,cd.category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c, " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd WHERE p2c.product_id = '".$product_id."' AND cd.category_id = p2c.category_id AND cd.category_id != 1");    
       return $query->rows;
}
```

If your product select under more then one category then it will give array of result otherwise it will give one result.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but after add these codes, how can i echo this variable in product.tpl ?

Answer (score 0):

Pedram,
If you do not want to select product into multiple category then change following code.

product.php(Controller)

```
$data['category_title'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryName($this->request->get['product_id']);
```

category.php(Model)

```
public function getCategoryName($product_id) { 
$query = $this-db-query("SELECT DISTINCT(cd.name),p2c.product_id,cd.category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c, " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd WHERE p2c.product_id = '".$product_id."' AND cd.category_id = p2c.category_id AND cd.category_id != 1");     

return $query-row;}
```

product.tpl (View)

```
<?php echo $category_title;?>
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: category_title in /homepages/5/d394528336/htdocs/Shop/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl on line 142`

Comment: I add your code but got above error. should i insert this code in certain line? or no matter how to paste these?

Comment: Which version are you using ?

Comment: Make controller code before the $data['options'] = array(); and then check

Comment: echo $data['category_title'] = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryName($this->request->get['product_id']);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109643/discussion-between-vipul-jethva-and-pedram-alipour).

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING) in...` are you sure it have `echo` ?

Comment: Yes, its echo result. You need learn more about opencart structure. Above code working fine in my product may be you need to double check code in your site.

Answer (score 0):

I know late to answer but i might help others . Tested in Opencart 2.3.0.2

To Show category in Product page.

You have to edit some of the opencart files.
Go to Controllors > product > product.php

Find the following line

$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

As we need the category for the product list we need the product_id for each products in the list

```
$this->load->model('catalog/category');
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryName($this->request->get['product_id']); if ($categories)
                                    {
                                                           $categories_info= $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($categories[0]['category_id']);
                                                            $data['category_title']  = $categories_info['name']; 
                                                            $data['category_text'] = "Category : ";
                                                            //print_r($categories_info['name']);
                                                           // $this->data['category_title'] = $categories_info['name'];
                                    }
```

Now Go to Model > Catalog > Category and you need to create a new function 
getCategoryName that we used in controller

```
  public function getCategoryName($product_id) {
                                  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(cd.name),p2c.product_id,cd.category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c, " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd WHERE p2c.product_id = '".$product_id."' AND cd.category_id = p2c.category_id AND cd.category_id != 1");    
                                                    return $query->rows;
                    }
```

Now go to View > theme > themename > template > product > product.tpl and add following line where you want to show category

```
<?php echo $category_text; ?><?php echo $category_title; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this. If you do not want to select product into multiple categories then change the following code.

**(catalog/controller/product/product.php) - path to controller file
(system/storage/modification/catalog/controller/product/product.php) - path to opencart controller file**

Past this code on two file our controller. I past before this line: `$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);`

Because we will already have our product id in variable:

```
$category_information = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryName($product_id);

if ($category_information) {
    $data['category_name'] = $category_information['name'];
}
```

**(catalog/model/catalog/category.php) - path to model file**

Past this code before last close sign "}". You create new function in our class of model:

```
public function getCategoryName($product_id) { 
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT(cd.name),p2c.product_id,cd.category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c, " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd WHERE p2c.product_id = '".$product_id."' AND cd.category_id = p2c.category_id AND cd.category_id != 1");     
return $query->row;
}
```

**(catalog/view/theme/nameyoutheme/template/product/product.tpl)**
And paste this code wherever you need on product tpl. I past after `<ul class="breadcrumb">...</ul>`:

```
<?php if(isset($category_name)){ ?>
    <div class="heading-title">
        <h1><?=$category_name;?></h1>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And that's all folks.

P.S. OpenCart Version 2.3.0.2